# Grep inside while loop bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to grep some info from a directory for each line in a file. I am using while loop to grep each line of a file. The grep alone works perfectly. I tested my while loop with echo and it works perfectly but when I use grep inside it gives me no output.

```
while IFS= read -r LINE; do
grep --include=\requests-definition.const.ts -rnwH $DIR -e "$LINE";
echo $LINE;
done < key_list
```

my key_list is a text file having a key on each line.
when I use the grep alone it works but  it may not work In a while loop.

Thanks !

Comment: Try to run it with `set -x` to see which commands are executed exactly

Comment: Just `grep -f key_list`

Comment: Hello, after using set -x the grep commands from the output are correct and should work but no output is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you loop is not exiting at the first Line without match.

From grep Man

EXIT STATUS

```
  Normally  the  exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if
   an error occurred.  However, if the -q or  --quiet  or  --silent  is  used  and  a  line  is
   selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred.
```

To aviod exiting you have several ways to go:

1. Use a subshell with $(grep ...)
2. use the flag set +e

```sh
    while IFS= read -r LINE; do

    set +x # don't exit if exit code is different from 0
    grep --include=\requests-definition.const.ts -rnwH $DIR -e "$LINE";
    set -e # exit if exit code is different from 0

    echo $LINE;
    done < key_list
```

Comment: After using this, the program exits at the first line, so why the grep wont't work inside the loop when it works alone ?

Comment: I have tested the code and it is working. Make sure the keys in key_list are finished with new line.

    cat key_list
    ok_key1\n
    ok_key2\n
    nok_key

Comment: Hello, the problem was solved by removing special characters from key_list using dos2unix command.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved by removing special characters from key_list using dos2unix command.